# GridLayout cardview getting out of screen Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I am trying to make an app using GridLayout, CardView and LinearLayout so everything works fine on the emulator but when I test my app on real devices the card view goes out of the screen I have tested it on different devices but the problem still occurs please help!

[This is how it looks inside the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWgRE.png)

[This is how it looks on a real device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXgVv.jpg)

XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_img"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:rowCount="4">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#DE773C"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="TEST"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#272932"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#DE773C"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="TEST"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#272932"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try changing the layout_width of both CardViews to either match_parent or wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your widths and heights are hard coded: `170dp`, `80dp`, etc. What you have done is to design a layout that works for the layout and size of the designer screen. The layout breaks when the screen width/height changes as it does when you move to an emulator or real device.

Take a look at [Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) about how to approach layout that work on different screen sizes. It takes some doing, but is necessary unless your app will only run on one configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want width of both CardViews same in all devices then try to add below in your GridLayout

Add `android:columnCount="2"` and `android:orientation="horizontal"` to `GridLayout`

Add `android:layout_width="0dp"`  and `android:layout_columnWeight="1"` to CardViews

Example Code:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:rowCount="4">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#DE773C"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="TEST"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#272932"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#DE773C"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="TEST"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#272932"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</GridLayout>
```